# Calling a cell's numeric value

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I want to use VBA to call a cell's numeric value, then use said value in another VBA function. I am currently getting an "Invalid outside procedure" Compile error on line two of my code. I have attempted to solve the error by using various solutions I've come across online mainly being different variations of "Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2") and Dim num As Range/Integer/String but am at a loss as to what is actually causing the error.

My code is as follows

```
Dim num As Range
num = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")

Function hold(x)
hold = 24 * x
End Function
Function vel(t)
vel = hold(1) * t - num * t ^ 2
End Function

Function Position(x0, t1, t2)

'define range of integral
int_range = t2 - t1

'discretize the integral into n slices dt wide
n = 1000
dt = int_range / n

'initialize variables
ta = t1
tb = ta + dt
Position = x0

'calculate areas using trapezoidal rule

'sum area under curve of each slice
For j = 1 To n
Position = Position + (tb - ta) * (vel(ta) + vel(tb)) / 2
ta = tb
tb = ta + dt
Next

End Function
```

Comment: Share with us what you have done to try to solve the problem.

Comment: You can't have `num = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")` outside a sub or function. If you add `Option Explicit` at the top, it should highlight this. You should set that value in the sub/function you are calling the other functions from (or where you need that `num`, and pass it as a parameter to the other function)

Comment: Why not move `num = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")` inside of the definition of `vel`?

Comment: Better update your question... comments are not great with code.

Comment: I've commented out the original ```num = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2")``` and moved it inside the definition of ```vel``` but was unfortunately left with an #VALUE! error on the cell that calls the final Position function. This does seem to rid my code of the original "Invalid Outside Procedure" error though.

Comment: you've declared `num` as range, you need to do `Set num = Worksheets("Sheet16").Range("E2")`, but that might likely cause you other problems. Alternatively declare `num` as the appropriate data type instead.

Comment: Adding Set fixed my problem! Thank you for your help, it was very appreciated.